# Simulink Floating-Point and Fixed-Point Modeling

Tags: matlab

I have not used Simulink extensively. I would like to know how to determine if a model is fixed-point or floating-point. Also, how to convert from fixed-point [back] to floating-point. The posts on the internet mostly discuss floating-point to fixed-point conversion. I need fixed-point to floating-point to learn and be able to use both floating-point and fixed-point models.

Answer (score 1):

The model is fixed point if it contains a single block with the data type setting "fixdt()". If you want to override the fixed-point settings you should go in your Simulink model to Analysis then open "Fixed-point Tool". There you should change "Data Type Override" from "Use local settings" to something else.